# Integrate $\int \prod_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{(x+i)}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I initially tried to find a pattern using partial fraction decomposition:
$$
n= 1 \, : \, \, \frac{1}{x(x+1)} = \frac{1}{x}+\frac{-1}{x+1}
$$

$$
n=2 \, : \, \, \frac{1}{x(x+1)(x+2)} = \frac{1/2}{x}+\frac{-1}{x+1}+\frac{1/2}{x+2}
$$

$$
n=3 \, : \, \, \frac{1}{x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)} = \frac{1/6}{x}+\frac{-1/2}{x+1}+\frac{1/2}{x+2} + \frac{-1/6}{x+3}
$$

$$
n=4 \, : \, \, \frac{1}{x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)} = \frac{1/24}{x}+\frac{-1/6}{x+1}+\frac{1/4}{x+2} + \frac{-1/6}{x+3} + \frac{1/24}{x+4}
$$
But I don't seem to find a pattern. Is there another method to resolve this? Thank you.

Comment: $$\prod _{i=0}^n \frac{1}{x+i}=\frac{\Gamma (x)}{\Gamma (x+n+1)}$$ It is hard to integrate the RHS, tho.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{x(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n)}=\sum_{k =0}^{n} 
\frac{(-1)^k }{k!(n-k)!}\frac{1}{x+k}
$$ https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3915792/integration-of-frac1xx1x2-xm/3915860#3915860

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint. If we have that
$$\prod_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{(x+i)}=\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{A_i}{(x+i)}.$$
then, for $k=0,\dots,n$,
$$\lim_{x\to -k}(x+k)\prod_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{(x+i)}=A_k.$$
The general formula of $A_k$ is related to a [*binomial coefficient*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

Once that the partial fraction decomposition is ready, the integration is straightforward.

Comment: @Robert_Z I have noticed that: $$
n=4 \, : \, \, \frac{1}{x(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)} = \frac{1}{4!x}+\frac{-1}{3!(x+1)}+\frac{1}{2!(x+2)} + \frac{-1}{3!(x+3)} + \frac{1}{4!(x+4)}
$$ But I just have some difficulty expressing this in terms of $n!$ and $i!$. $$\frac{n!}{i!(n-i)!}$$ doesnt seem to work

Comment: @StanislasCASTELLANA Your coefficient for $1/(x+2)$ is wrong. To see how it works, write the general case, with arbitrary $n$ and $k$. The factors before the (removed) $x+k$ will yield $(-k)(-k+1)...(-1)$, and the factors after $x+k$ will yield $(1)(2)...(n-k)$. Clearer now?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I am just unsure what you mean by the removed $x+k$? But Thank you

Comment: @StanislasCASTELLANA When you compute the limit of $(x+k)\prod_{i=0}^n\dfrac{1}{x+i}$, you are removing the factor $x+k$ from the product. The goal is to be able to replace $x$ with $-k$ to annihilate all terms of the partial fraction decomposition, except the term in $\dfrac{1}{x+k}$. It's the standard way of expanding in partial fraction for simple roots.

Comment: @StanislasCASTELLANA Yes, After removing the factor  $(x+k)$, and taking the limit we find $\frac{1}{(-k)(-k+1)...(-1)(1)(2)...(n-k)}$ which is related with the binomial coefficient $\binom{n}{k}$.

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

$$\prod_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{x+k}=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k-1} \frac{k{n \choose k}}{x(x+k)}=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k-1} {n \choose k} [\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x+k}]$$
So $$\int \prod_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{x+k} dx=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(-1)^{k-1} {n \choose k}[\ln x- \ln (x+k)]$$

Comment: there is something wrong. Should be $$\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{(-1)^{k+1} \left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{k+x}\right) \binom{n}{k}}{n!}$$

Comment: You probably mean, for $n>0$, $$\prod_{k=0}^n\frac1{x+k}=\frac1{n!}\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\frac{k\binom{n}{k}}{x(x+k)}$$ Although I don't see how it's simpler than Robert Z's answer.

Comment: Oh ! yes I shoul fill in $n!$ and $k-1$., thanks.